# GDAL how to assign value=0 to pixels outside the shapefile without change the size and resolution of tif?

Tags: tiff, gdal, shapefile

I am facing problem with assign nodata value (could be 0) outside the shapefile to set of tiff tiles. I have a lot of tifs where I have 2 bands. Each file have exactly the same size (600x600 pixels) and the same resolution (0.5m/px).

Most of them are inside of the AOI shapefile. I would like to set value=0 or nodata(for both bands) for those pixeles which are outside the shapefile.

I tried GDALWrap and cutline paramter but the output tif is whith shapefile dimensions...
Any ideas how to achive that?
Thanks!